# Bitbucket Origin does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: github, bitbucket

Im trying to init a new project to Bitbucket and according to Bitbucket documentation. I have used the following commands

```
git remote set-url origin urlofthegitrepo

git push -u origin master
```

but i get  Origin does not appear to be a git repository Error.

Comment: If you have a bare repo on Bitbucket, then there should be a dummy page there which will give you the exact URL to which you should be pushing.  Have you tried accessing this page?

Comment: I did everything as the dummy page said.

Comment: Check the answer below, I believe you need `git remote add` not `git remote set-url`.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. bit bucket demo page said set-url. but thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try these commands.

Instead of

```
git remote set-url origin url
```

try

```
git remote add origin url
```

And then Add and commit and finally push

```
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Try these and see
Cheers xD

Comment: Thanks this worked.  git remote add origin saved my day :D